# Unable to print without quotes in csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple

I am trying to print a table from .csv file which is generated by libreoffice in such a way one of the column has a value comma separated e.g `John,Terang` i want to print `John, Terang` without any quotes, but it seems to be printed as `"John,Terang"` because when i open in text editor actual value it shows as `"{John,Terang}"` so it printed as `"John,Terang"` how do i print as `John,Terang` without modifying .csv file
Till now i have try so far,

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{csvsimple}
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
 SlNo,Name,Occupation
 1,Daniel Rongpi,"{a,b}"
 2,"{John, Terang}","{service, fire}"
 3,ffdfdf,wewe
 \end{filecontents*}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
 \hline
 Sl.No. & Name & Occupation\\\hline
 \csvreader[head to column names]{file.csv}{}
 {\SlNo & \Name & \Occupation\\\hline
 }

 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The ouput of the above code is shown below
[image]

but output which i want is something like this  without modifying the .csv file

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `csvsimple` to ignore `"`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
SlNo,Name,Occupation
1,Daniel Rongpi,"{a,b}"
2,"{John, Terang}","{service, fire}"
3,ffdfdf,"we we"
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  tabular=|l|l|l|,
  table head=\hline Sl.No. & Name & Occupation \\\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline,
  head to column names,
  before reading={\catcode`\"=9}
]{\jobname.csv}{}
 {%
  \SlNo & \Name & \Occupation
 }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The magician appears with his TeX tricks :):):)

Comment: Thank you so much . I want to add something how do i tell csvsimple to make for grouping i.e whenever it founds `" some text, other text"` grouping as single block@egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron I'm afraid this is out of the scope for `csvsimple`

Comment: @egreg I have found something from this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode but i was unable to apply just like you have used `\catcode` command.

Comment: @BikiTeron As far as I can see, `csvsimple` is not able to cope with `"` delimited entries for hiding a comma.

Comment: @egreg ok thank you so much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `csvsimple`, you could use `pgfplotstable`, which allows you to ignore some chars with `ignore chars={"}`.

I also advise you to use `booktabs` for table formatting.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}  

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
    SlNo,Name,Occupation
    1,Daniel Rongpi,"{a,b}"
    2,"{John, Terang}","{service, fire}"
    3,ffdfdf,wewe
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{With your table style}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,ignore chars={"},
        col sep=comma,
        columns/SlNo/.style={column type={|l|}, column name={Sl.No.}},
        columns/Name/.style={column type={l|}},
        columns/Occupation/.style={column type={l|}},
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\hline},
        ]{file.csv}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \caption{Or, better, with \texttt{booktabs} style}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,ignore chars={"},
        col sep=comma,
        columns/SlNo/.style={column type={l}, column name={Sl.No.}},
        columns/Name/.style={column type={l}},
        columns/Occupation/.style={column type={l}},
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule},
        ]
        {file.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]