# trouble with a simple csvsimple and csvautotabular table

Tags: csvsimple

I have a csv file, `keywords_table.csv`. I made it in Excel. Here it is:

```
Keyword Category,Number of keywords used in searches,Examples
Names of drugs,111,"tamoxifen, aspirin, tamiflu"
Names of categories,15,"cancer drug, NSAID, flu vaccine"
"Synonyms for ""child"" and ""pediatric""",11,"pediatric, child, prepubertal, adolescent, teenage, early life, kid"
Names of physiological systems,47,"urinary, hematologic, cardiovascular, musculoskeletal, endocrine, sensory, reproductive, skin, salivary"
Names and synonyms of adverse drug reactions,10,"adverse event, adverse reaction, side effect, adverse drug reaction, AE, ADR, ADE"
Exclusion terms,5,"mouse, mice, rat, animal model, scale, addict"
```

My goal: put a table in my LaTeX document. I'd like to do it with a separate csv file, since that's easier to update for me in other software instead of having to change values manually inside a standard Latex table.

I've been trying for a few hours now to use `csvsimple` to do so, but I haven't succeeded. I've read through that package's documentation and various examples online to try and get this thing to work, but no dice. I'm very much a LaTeX novice, so I apologize if this is a trivial question.

My LaTeX workflow is MikTex on Windows 10 Pro, and I'm using TexMaker. I'm rendering with XeLaTeX and BibTex. Here's the code I use to try and get the table going with `csvautotabular`, including my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\doublespacing
\usepackage{anysize}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/stuff/bib.bib}

\title{HEY LOOK A TITLE}
\author{ME}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\csvautotabular{keywords_table.csv}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The code executes perfectly well if I remove `\csvautotabular{keywords_table.csv}`. That's all I'm trying to do. I don't care about formatting or anything.

Here's a screenshot of the litany of error messages that TexMaker spits back to me when I try to run XeLaTeX:

[image: Errors]

These are uninterpretable to me. Where is it inserting anything? I've gone through my whole document to see if there were missing {'s or }'s to no avail. Like I said, the document runs without the `\csvautotabular` line.

Sorry again for this. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait and see if there are better answers since I have very little experience with this type of import 
[image]

However here is my novice attempt at above. I have had to modify your csv to suite the loading method so a modified copy to simplify \headings and "{include, commas}" is imbedded in the following, once it runs save out the filecontents to an external file as testing.csv delete that section and see how it loads.  In your own solution the csv can be any external name.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{csquotes} % had problems trying to get complex file to use this package
%\MakeOuterQuote{''} % had problems trying to get complex file to use this package
\usepackage{csvsimple} %csvsimple is not able to cope reliably with " delimited comma entries
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % I usually have problems with this family 
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\doublespacing
\usepackage{anysize}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa
]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{C:/stuff/bib.bib} % don't have this stuff

% filecontents for demo can be external as per comment below
\begin{filecontents*}{testing.csv} 
Category,Number,Examples
Names of drugs,111,"{tamoxifen, aspirin, tamiflu}"
Names of categories,15,"{cancer drug, NSAID, flu vaccine}"
"Synonyms for child and pediatric",11,"{pediatric, child, prepubertal, adolescent, teenage, early life, kid}"
Names of physiological systems,47,"{urinary, hematologic, cardiovascular, musculoskeletal, \cr && endocrine, sensory, reproductive, skin, salivary}"
Names and synonyms of adverse drug reactions,10,"{ADE, adverse drug event, ADR, adverse drug reaction, \cr && AE, adverse event, AR, adverse reaction, SE, side effect}"
Exclusion terms,5,"{mouse, mice, rat, animal model, scale, addict}"
\end{filecontents*}

\title{HEY LOOK A TITLE}
\author{ME}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\csvautotabular{keywords_table.csv} replaced with modifications per answer by egreg
%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424207/unable-to-print-without-quotes-in-csvsimple
\tiny \csvreader[
  tabular=|l|c|l|,
  table head=\hline Keyword Category & Searches & Examples of each\\\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline,
  head to column names,
  before reading={\catcode`\"=9}
]{testing.csv}{} % you can replace "testing" with "keywords_table" filename
 {%
  \Category & \Number & \Examples
 }%

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd seen solutions based on `begin{filecontents*}` but have avoided them for now since I'd like to avoid having to update a table's values inside the latex document. But if that's where I end up, that's what I have to do I guess.

Comment: Its only included for demo it will work with that section as a separate file

Comment: Ohhhh okay! My mistake, I apologize. I'll try it and see how it goes. Thanks again!